# local headphone enabled FM radio app for nexus 5 (no internet needed)

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, nexus-5, fm-radio

I just moved from S3 to nexus 5, and there are a couple of things that I miss from my s3.. one is the prepackaged FM radio app.. all i needed was my headphones and I could connect directly to the local stations.. is there such an app for nexus 5 (and other android devices in general)? apps like [tune in](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tunein.player) require wi-fi or 3g, which isn't what i'm looking for. I'm looking to be able to connect to the local radio on the go without 3g.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, Nexus 5 does not have a FM radio (just checked the specs at [GSMArena.com](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_5-5705.php)).

So, you cannot listen to your local FM broadcast and should rely only on online radio stations.

Comment: ahhh damn that sucks big time man!

Comment: I have seen an unbranded headset with in built radio. It was powered by a pair of LR44 button cells. The interesting feature about it is that while making calls, the radio stops and allows user to hear the call. The radio resumes at the end of the call. I am not sure how this behave when a music is played in the phone. You may try using these kind of headphones as an substitute.

Comment: Nexus 4 and 5, Galaxy S4 and S5, HTC One  none of the newer ones have FM radio. They seem to have sacrificed for space/newer features / figure people use streaming services now. There's still a gap between data rates and availability and raido though, not everyone can stream happily away all day and the FM filled that gap.

Answer (score -1):

Best option is to get a Bluetooth with FM ( Sony MW600). Once paired to yr Nexus 5. When you will get calls the FM will stop and resumes after yr call is disconnected.

Comment: What's a "Bluetooth with FM"? Is it an FM radio that connects to your phone via Bluetooth?

Answer (score -1):

As Ramni said, its good to go for Bluetooth head set with fm. it serves 2 main purpose.

1. connect to your through Bluetooth (Wireless), so that you can answer call and listen to music stored in your phone.
2. since it has in built radio, you can use it with out your phone for listening to radio while taking morning walk or some thing.

But the drawback is.

1. Device is little expensive.
2. need to charge the device.